# Pattern syntax error

Tags: java, regex

The following regex works in the find dialog of Eclipse but throws an exception in Java.

I can't find why

```
(?<=(00|\\+))?[\\d]{1}[\\d]*
```

The syntax error is at runtime when executing:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=(00|\\+))?[\\d]{1}[\\d]*")
```

In the find I used

```
(?<=(00|\+))?[\d]{1}[\d]*
```

I want to match phone numbers with or without the + or 00. But that is not the point because I get a Syntax error at position 13. I don't get the error if I get rid of the second "?"

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=(00|\\+))[\\d]{1}[\\d]*")
```

Please consider that instead of 1 sometime I need to use a greater number and anyway the question is about the syntax error

Comment: Could you provide error message ?

Comment: What strings do you want to match?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but your regex looks like it is equivalent to `\d+`.

Comment: And also please provide your Java code that throws the exception.

Comment: What you want to achieve? Show us some input and expected output

Comment: The error is written in the title of the post: Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looks like `00ddddd` or `+ddddd` where d is digit you want to get [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11451509/1393766)'s regex `(?<=00|\\+)\\d+` will do the trick. But if your data sometimes don't have any part that you want to ignore like `ddddd` then you probably should use group mechanism like

```
String[] data={"+123456","00123456","123456"};
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?:00|\\+)?(\\d+)");
Matcher m=null;
for (String s:data){
    m=p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

output

```
123456
123456
123456
```

Comment: What about if you replace your regexp with mine. Do you get the syntax error?

Comment: Are you sure you checked the exact pattern? I get a Syntax error at position 13 with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might shorten your regex a lot. The character classes are not needed when there is only one class inside - just use `\d`. And `{1}` is quite useless as well. Also, you can use `+` for matching "one or more" (it's short for `{1,}`). Next the additional grouping in your lookbehind should not be needed.

And last, why is that lookbehind optional (with `?`)? Just leave it away if you don't need it. This might even be the source of your pattern syntax error - a lookaround must not be optional.

Try this:

```
/(?<=00|\+)\d+/
```

Java:

```
"(?<=00|\\+)\\d+"
```

Comment: Hi. Thank-you. There are other reason why I need to do that. I still did not find why I get the syntax error

Comment: So, the syntax error position is the "?" to make your lookbehind optional?

Comment: Does Eclipse use the Java regexp compiler *and* does it report all the errors to you, or does it try to be clever and remove the broken things when it catches a exception?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=00|\\+)(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("+1123456");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
```